# SPFX Fabric UI React Buttons handled by one click event

Tags: spfx, react, office-ui-fabric-react

I need to put multiple CompoundButtons on my SPFX webpart, I need them to trigger the same onClick event handler.

How do I know in my event which button has fired? I tried to use an id, but it seems React (sometimes) changes this ID with it's own internal one.

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IReportingProps> {
    return (
     <div>
              <CompoundButton id='button1' ariaLabel='Button1' description='First button description' onClick={ this._RequestButton}>Button 1</CompoundButton> 
              <CompoundButton id='Button2' ariaLabel='Button2' description='Second button description' onClick={ this._RequestButton}>Button 2</CompoundButton> 
          </div>
          <div> Result: {this.state.result}</div>
 );
  }



@autobind
  private _RequestButton(e:any):void{
      this.setState({
        result: e.target.id
      });
  }
```

The above code, some clicks the etarget.id is button1 or button2 other times it can be ID__101
Is there another property I should use to determine which button fired? I don't want to use the Title of the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve but you can call your method like this:

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IReportingProps> {
  return (
    <div>
        <CompoundButton id='button1' ariaLabel='Button1' description='First button description' onClick={ () => this._RequestButton('Button 1')}>Button 1</CompoundButton> 
        <CompoundButton id='Button2' ariaLabel='Button2' description='Second button description' onClick={ () => this._RequestButton('Button 2')}>Button 2</CompoundButton> 
    </div>
    <div> Result: {this.state.result}</div>
  );
}

@autobind
private _RequestButton(value: string):void{
  this.setState({
    result: value
  });
}
```

Comment: Of course. That makes sense to do it this way.